# How to display list from database using a specific column in the table in laravel

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I have a table users with a column name 'role' and the roles are admin and users, now I want to display the in the page the users only, how should I do it? I'm a beginner. please help. I'm using laravel 8.

Comment: you want to query the users table with the role `users`, right??

Comment: oh I apologize, it's customer. I have a users table and inside the table there's a column named role, and the roles are admin and customers

Comment: okay..so what do you want now?? what is the expected output you want??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly but I believe what you are after is the following:

**Admins**
user 1
User 2

**Users**
User 3
User 4

Is that correct? if so The `User::class` must have a relation to the `Role::class` and the `Role::class` must have a relation to the users, e.g. a User has one role and a Role has many users.

```
$roles = Role::all()->with('users');
```

and in the blade

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
    <h1>{{ $role->title }}</h1>
    @foreach($role->users as $user)
        {{ $user->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Just query the table with eloquent

$users= Users::where('role','customers')->get()